# How to use limit and order by clause with fmdb database for retrieve table data?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, fmdb

I am using `FMDB` database for my `iOS` application and I want to retrieve table data using order by and limit clause but FMDB gives following error.

I am posting my query statement and error message.

Query-

```
 [cmdatabase open];
  NSString *query = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from MessagesTable where fromUserName=%@ OR toUserName=%@ ORDER BY messageTimestamp DESC LIMIT %d",
                                 userName, userName, limetNo];

  FMResultSet *results = [cmdatabase executeQuery:query];
```

Error Message-

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) 
 [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not using the *, instead, write select from. I had some issues in sqlite on this.